# concatenating scss file with lots of other scss files

Tags: gulp

I have the next files structure:

```
modules/
    list/
        news/
            news.scss
        login/
            login.scss
    common/
        common.scss
```

And I want to get next structure using gulp:

```
modules/
    list/
        news/
            news.scss
            news.css
        login/
            login.scss
            login.css
    common/
        common.scss
```

Here is part from my gulpfile:

```
gulp.src("modules/list/*/*.scss")
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("modules/list/"));
```

In common.scss there are different variables. It is necessary that variables from common.scss will be used in each module(news.scss, login.scss). How to update my gulpfile that common.scss will be concatenated with each module scss file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for stream arrays... here's the solution, please check the comments for what's going on:

```js
var merge = require('merge2');
var glob = require('glob');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function(done) {
    // first, we glob our files like we would with gulp.src
    glob('modules/list/**/*.scss', function(er, files) {
        // for each of those files we create a new stram
        var tasks = files.map(function(file) {
            // this gives us the concat name, which is the same
            // as the original file's name
            var concatStr = file.substr('modules/list/'.length)
            // we load common.scss and our file
            return gulp.src(['modules/common/common.scss', file])
            // concatenate it
                .pipe(concat(concatStr))
        });

        // we merge all our streams
        merge(tasks)
        // run them through sass
            .pipe(sass())
        // and save them where we want them
            .pipe(gulp.dest('modules/list'));
        // ~fin
        done();
    });
});
```

You might want to take a look into Sass's `@import` directive, though.

Comment: I do not want to use Sass's @import directive because it is necessary to use this directive in each file manually. Your solution looks good, but what about performance?

Comment: Hard to say.. there'll be some overhead due to double-globbing (with the second being faster, tough), but the rest should work out ok. Merge runs parallel, so it might actually boost up your speed a little